# Merging a gif image with a png image

Tags: image, animation, merge, png, gif

I'd like to merge this ordinary png file:

[image]

with this gif animation:

[image: And here]
<sub>(source: [mytree.co.il](http://mytree.co.il/sub/explosion.gif))</sub>

I don't want to use css' position and Z-index, it messes up my images which are located in table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to make gif image, try GIMP. Here are steps to make gif image with GIMP.

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Animated-GIF-Image-with-GIMP

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the gif frames with a software like http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-extract-frames-from-gif-animation-image/
2. Use photoshop, GIMP or any similar image editor to merge the background to the images. Tools like magic wands with a precise threshold might help in the matter
3. Put it all together into a new gif file

Good luck

Comment: First of all, thanks.
I've extracted the frames to photoshop and replaced the background and saved it as a new gif but when I open the file, it doesn't play. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps a wrong loop: most gif editors will have a checkbox for "repeat" or "loop infinitely". Did you set that as you desire it?